# prototype.js issues

Tags: prototypejs

I am trying to migrate my application from prototype 1.5 to 1.7

However I get errors using `getElementsByClassName`

My piece of code looks something like this

```
this.top = Element.getHeight(Element.getElementsByClassName(cell.element,"Day")[0])
```

However I get javascript error "Element.getElementsByClassName is not a function"

Any idea how to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Make your Prototype code more Prototype-y.

```
this.top = cell.element.down('.Day').getHeight();
```